# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors for matrix

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
datTraits = as.matrix(Phenotype[traitRows, ]);
Col_A = as.data.frame(datTraits$Col_A);

Error in datTraits$Col_A : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I am trying to solve this error but could not find the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The 'datTraits' is a `matrix`.  So `$` won't work.  We can use `[`

```
datTraits[, "Col_A"])
```

In the OP's code, if we are using `as.data.frame`, note the extraction with `$` i.e. after the `)`

```
as.data.frame(datTraits)$Col_A
```

---

If we have a matrix with 5 columns and want to subset the first two columns

```
as.data.frame(datTraits[, 1:2])
```

If we are subsetting only a single column, to avoid dropping the dimensions, use `drop = FALSE`

```
out <- as.data.frame(datTraits[, "Col_A", drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked but in the next step names(Col_A)="Col_A. It gives all NA values and I got error.

Comment: @Jessican If you are creating a data.frame with only 'Col_A', then do `data.frame(Col_A = datTraits[, "Col_A"])`

Comment: I have a data frame with five columns and I am making data.frame with first column NAME and second column "Col_A". Your code worked for creating a data.frame but when I do names(Col_A)="Col_A". I still get all NA's.

Comment: @Jessica If you have five columns, just subset the dataset `out <- as.data.frame(datTraits[, c("NAME", "Col_A"), drop = FALSE])`